# Finding unique column pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say my table looks like this:

```
1. user 1.2.3.4
2. user 1.2.3.4
3. user 2.3.4.5
4. user 2.3.4.5
5. user 1.2.3.5
6. anotheruser 1.2.3.6
7. anotheruser 1.2.3.4
```

I want to get list of all ips with usernames. The query may look like this:

```
select username, ip from client_logs where ip is unique
```

I want output like this:

```
user 1.2.3.4
user 2.3.4.5
user 1.2.3.5
anotheruser 1.2.3.6
anotheruser 1.2.3.4
```

I already tried to do it by select distinct, but I have only ips, or ip - user. The query I've tried is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip, username
FROM client_logs
ORDER BY username
```

Comment: can you show what query you try?

Comment: you can use either `select distinct ...`, or you can group by: `select user, ip from client_logs group by user, ip`.

Answer (score 3):

USE `GROUP BY`

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90e4d/4)

```
SELECT username, ip
FROM client_logs
GROUP BY username, ip
ORDER BY username, ip
```

**Edit**

I also try your first solution and works

[**Only distinct DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90e4d/5)

```
SELECT distinct username, ip
FROM client_logs
ORDER BY username, ip
```

Comment: @encoreleet I edit my answer, your query doesnt work for the data you suply. check this [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90e4d/4)

Comment: @encoreleet I try your sql distinct and also work. Why give you problem that query?

Comment: This answer works to provide the data OP said they wanted in the question. I'm not sure why they think this doesn't work.

Comment: @McAdam331, Yes I try to create another way to get around OP solution. But when create the fiddle saw was working as expected.

Comment: It's good to keep both for demonstration purposes, but both of your queries should return the same result, correct?

Comment: @McAdam331 Correct. I include both fiddle and return same result.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by following query:

```
SELECT username, ip
FROM client_logs
GROUP BY ip
ORDER BY username, ip
```

Comment: This will only show one row per IP. Are you sure that's what you want? What if multiple users logged in from the same IP? This query won't give you the expected results you said you wanted in the question.